# How to decrypt QRcode in TelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, api, qr-code, py-telegram-bot-api

I am creating a telegram bots that can generate and decrypt QRcodes. I implemented the creation of a QR code using BytesIO:

```
#bot creating a qrcode
@bot.message_handler(commands=['create'])
def creating_qr(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Enter text and ill generate QRcode')
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    def creating_qr(message):
        qr_img = qrcode.make(message.text)
        bio = BytesIO()
        qr_img.save(bio, 'JPEG')
        bio.seek(0)
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, bio)
```

I tried to decrypt qrcode using the same method, but the ApiTelegramBot documentation says `photo` is a list so I can't save it in a BytesIO. How can I save `photo` and then decrypt it?

Method that I tried:

```
def decrypting(message):
    detector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
    qr_image = message.photo
    bio = BytesIO()
    qr_image.save(bio, 'JPEG')
    bio.seek(0)
    data = detector.detectAndDecode(bio)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'QR code data: \n\n{data}')
```

Comment: Hi Valeriy, welcome to stackoverflow! You should not put things like the programming language in the title, instead use tags for that (as you did).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used the API myself, but Pyhton and Telegram :) A message can have multiple photos. So I guess you get a list of photos. In order to select the first photo, change your code like so:

```
qr_image = message.photo[0]
```